# Why does my 3DS claim I have no space on my 4GB SD card while it looks empty?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

I have a 4GB SD card, but when I try to update a game on my 3DS it always says "You need x more open block(s) to download this.". When I look at my Data Management, the software, extra data and DLC on the card are all displayed as empty. Why does my 3DS claim that I have no space on my SD card?

[image: Photos of the screen of my 3DS]

Comment: Out of curiosity, what game are you trying to download? It's possible the game itself is simply too large for the 4 GB SD card.

Comment: I'm trying to update animal crossing I havent updated it in a while...

Comment: New Leaf should take only about 1 GB, so the card should be large enough. You might have too many pictures, videos, or music files on it. If that still doesn't help, you can always try to buy a bigger card.

Answer (score 1):

SD cards can contain data other than 3DS-specific files. Free up some space in your SD card by using any file explorer, such as connecting it to a computer.

Comment: I did as you explained but there is still no space... Now it claims that I need 230 more blocks to download the game.

Comment: @DeathWish Then you need more space. Have you emptied the SD card?

Comment: When I looked at the SD card it was broken so I will just buy a new one. Thank you for your help.